# When only "All Exceptions" breakpoint is set, Xcode 7 always stop on app start

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, breakpoints, swift2

It's been bothering me since `Xcode 6`, that whenever I set 'All Exceptions' without any other breakpoints, `Xcode` would stop at start when I init a `UILabel` view wrapper in `RootVC`.

If I try to remove the causing line, another "random" line would trigger it again. Thoughts on what caused the exception[image]?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So there is nothing in the "Breakpoint navigator"? What does `breakpoint list` in the debugger console print when the execution has stopped?

Comment: Sorry @MartinR actually the All Exceptions is set (without that it's fine). Not sure why it throws though.
(lldb) breakpoint list
Current breakpoints:
1: names = {'objc_exception_throw', '__cxa_throw'}, locations = 2, resolved = 2, hit count = 1

  1.1: re-exported target = libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw, address = 0x00000001980e67d4, resolved, hit count = 1 
  1.2: where = libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, address = 0x0000000198a4ff48, resolved, hit count = 0

Comment: @Pankaj: Re your edit: The backticks are for `program code`, not for general emphasis. It makes no sense to format Xcode 6 as `Xcode 6`.

Comment: Mmm is the 1.1 "re-exported target = libc++abi.dylib" actually the cause of it?

Comment: @MartinR- I'm new to Reviewing, I'm getting familiar with the review Screen. Can you let me know how can I see different versions(Before Edit was made and After Edit), is there any way we can see the edits like we see in DiffMerge. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This breakpoint comes from an exception that was thrown by `TFileDescriptorContext`. `All Exceptions` halts also on C++ exceptions.

It gives you a good indication where the problem comes from. Take a look if all fonts that are listed in `Info.plist` are part of your application bundle.

"Normally" you are not interested in C++ exceptions when you are in Objective-C, so feel free to ignore them.

*Edit: This problem has been discussed several times here on SO. Updating when I can find the posts again which might give you even a deeper insight.*

Comment: Ah thanks! Searching for TFileDescriptorContext led me to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28116048/1032900

Comment: thanks, I added new font in Xcode project but didn't add its name to info.plist array