# Existing app crashes on startup on iPhone X Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar, xcode9, iphone-x

I have an existing app, that crashes on launch, when running on iPhone X Simulator. (Breakpoint stops on the main.m files).
The app runs fine on iPhone 8 simulator, so it has something to with iPhone X.
Also, it has something to do with the status bar, since the stack shows something with [UIStatusbar _prepareForVisualProviderIfNeeded] before the crash.

Do I need to do something with status bar to run this app on iPhone X Simulator?

Comment: Does adding Exception Breakpoint help?

Comment: pls post your stack trace

Comment: please note that status bar height is no longer 20 in iPhoneX

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [All exception break point is stopping for no reason on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375640/all-exception-break-point-is-stopping-for-no-reason-on-simulator)

TL;DR: Make sure that all fonts that you specify in your Info.plist under Fonts provided by this application are actually in your application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

UIStatusBar suggests that the crash might be due to your UI design in storyboard. Some constraints in old design conflict with iphone x's new status bar area.

Please check and fix it with the help of the new feature, SafeArea.

[New feature for ui constraints: safe area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUP1.jpg)