# App crashing on launch in iPhone x?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, iphone-x

I have developed an app with swift 4 & Xcode 9. Whenever i launch the app its crashes. It does not give any error on Console.

I studied it that it is the issue of the font.

[Existing app crashes on startup on iPhone X Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351831/existing-app-crashes-on-startup-on-iphone-x-simulator)

But my font is in my project and plist[image]

Some of them said that it is storyboard issue as the controller must have safe area margin. But few days back I run my app on iPhone X but it did not crash although it was not using safe area.

My app crashes in appdelegate as below screenshot

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: have you add your font in Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: have you tried other simulator like iPhone 8 for example? what's the result?

Comment: I have tried it running on iPhone 5,6,6+ simulator & also on device but it does not crash

Comment: I've never used a .ttc font in Xcode. Does Xcode support .ttc files?

Comment: Yes because it works on other devices

Comment: Is this problem still current?  Open the Xcode panel for the log and make sure it specifies all output.  Your SIGABRT can be caused by many things among them the storyboard  or a disconnected outlet.  The log will tell you what the exact problem is.debugging

Comment: Funny how I have the same problem. My App is crashing only on theX family. The iPhone 12 is fine! And I checked the fonts. The label on the first screen just remains nil when running iPhoneX simulator and crashes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add font extension also Ex. roboto.ttf

[image]

Comment: It is not a font file issue for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it's not specifically iPhone x simulator problem, you can run it on other simulators or real device to be sure about it.

you can find the step by step adding font to the Xcode project in this [thread](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

> Step 1: Include your fonts in your XCode project
>
> Step 2: Make sure that they’re included in the target
>
> Step 3: Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle
>
> Step 4: Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist
>
> Step 5: Find the name of the font
>
> Step 6: Use UIFont and specify the name of the font
> and also make sure that you've added the phone to the bundle resources:

Bundle Resources:
[image]

there is also another possibility of crash because of the font which is the incorrect font name in the code (if you used it programmatically). check the font name from `UIFont.familyNames`

Comment: It does not crash on any other device or simulator

Comment: I have share the screenshots for crash.Please check

Comment: so, you're sure that the crash didn't happen before that?
any console log?

Comment: I shared the screeenshot . No console logs. It works fine in all other devices and simualtor

Comment: Please provide an update on this? How can i get rid of crash

Comment: you should provide more information. like where and how did you use the font?
if is it programatically the code related to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159543/discussion-between-dhiraj-kumar-and-mina).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all for thier answers & helping me. Below are some points I would like to mention:

1. It was not a font issue for me.
2. It not a permission issue for me.

The library which I used is known as "**ROLLBAR**" was causing app to crash. When I removed the code for this library, I am able to run my app on iPhone X.

Comment: Dhiraj: Do you suppose you could shoot us an email at support@rollbar.com with a bit more info? Rollbar definitely shouldn't be causing your app to crash. We'd like to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18090559)

Comment: @Peanut please pay more attention when doing reviews. OP answered their own question, so even if you think this is not a good answer, your reasoning is definitely wrong.

Comment: I think it should have been a comment, either on the original question or one one of the answers. On the other hand, the Rollbar-part is new to the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, this is a permission issue.
Please check the required permissions in your app and give the appropriate permission strings.

If the problem persists, reset your simulator. This will make the simulator run fresh.

Please keep me posted.